# How to display time entered via jquery from database into a dropdown list

Tags: jquery, wordpress, select

I have created 2 select options for time in my plugin backend , one for hour and one for minute.

```
<select class="mon_1" name="mon_1"></select> <select class="monm_1" name="monm_1"></select>
```

i am getting the values using jquery and passing it via ajax. This is how i have given the values,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var i =1;
    for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
        jQuery('.mon_'+i).append('<option value="00">00</option><option value="01">01</option><option value="02">02</option><option value="03">03</option><option value="04">04</option><option value="05">05</option><option value="06">06</option><option value="07">07</option><option value="08">08</option><option value="09">09</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option>');
        jQuery('.monm_'+i).append('<option value="00">00</option><option value="01">01</option><option value="02">02</option><option value="03">03</option><option value="04">04</option><option value="05">05</option><option value="06">06</option><option value="07">07</option><option value="08">08</option><option value="09">09</option><option value="10">10</option><option value="11">11</option><option value="12">12</option><option value="13">13</option><option value="14">14</option><option value="15">15</option><option value="16">16</option><option value="17">17</option><option value="18">18</option><option value="19">19</option><option value="20">20</option><option value="21">21</option><option value="22">22</option><option value="23">23</option><option value="24">24</option><option value="25">25</option><option value="26">26</option><option value="27">27</option><option value="28">28</option><option value="29">29</option><option value="30">30</option><option value="31">31</option><option value="32">32</option><option value="33">33</option><option value="34">34</option><option value="35">35</option><option value="36">36</option><option value="37">37</option><option value="38">38</option><option value="39">39</option><option value="40">40</option><option value="41">41</option><option value="42">42</option><option value="43">43</option><option value="44">44</option><option value="45">45</option><option value="46">46</option><option value="47">47</option><option value="48">48</option><option value="49">49</option><option value="50">50</option><option value="51">51</option><option value="52">52</option><option value="53">53</option><option value="54">54</option><option value="55">55</option><option value="56">56</option><option value="57">57</option><option value="58">58</option><option value="59">59</option>')
```

and this is how i get the values :

```
var mon_1_time    = jQuery('.mon_1').val() + ':' + jQuery('.monm_1').val();
```

now i want to display the values in the select boxes when the page is refreshed, basically i want to retain the values even after the page is refreshed, what possible method can i adopt ?

Comment: " i want to retain the values even after the page is refreshed". You have to save them somewhere, either on the server, or alternatively localstorage or something.

Comment: For usual html, we can pass the value like below without storing, 
i am looking for such a method

 <option value="Pacific/Midway" <?php if($text[0]->time_zone == 'Pacific/Midway') echo 'selected'; ?>>(UTC-11:00) Midway Island, Samoa</option>

Comment: Ok so if the values of mon1 and monm1 are posted back to the server during a form submit, then you can set those next time in a similar way to you've just shown. But you'd have to build the option tags using PHP, not jQuery. Then when the page loads you can use those values to set the mon_1_time variable just like you do now.

Comment: yeah i know i can do that using php , but then i have to build the options value for 9 such days ... inorder to reduce that hassle only i have done it using jquery

Comment: There's nothing about the HTML you've created in the code above which couldn't be created using PHP instead. Especially since you do it at page load, so it basically would make no tangible difference to the page or the user